# SSH Keyboard Interactive authentication

Tags: objective-c, ios, authentication, libssh2

I currently try to extend an libssh2 Wrapper in Objective-C.

I'm trying to implement the `libssh2_userauth_keyboard_interactive` method. My problem is the response callback.

I found this implementation on the net that bypasses the "real" interactivity and uses the actual password to make the authentication possible:

```
int error = libssh2_userauth_keyboard_interactive(session, [username UTF8String], &kbdCallback);

static void kbdCallback (const char *name, int name_len, const char *instruction, int instruction_len, int num_prompts, const LIBSSH2_USERAUTH_KBDINT_PROMPT *prompts, LIBSSH2_USERAUTH_KBDINT_RESPONSE *responses, void **abstract)
{
    responses[0].text = (char *)[password UTF8String];   // resp. (char *)[@"test" UTF8String]
    responses[0].length = strlen([password UTF8String]); // resp. (char *)[@"test" UTF8String]
}
```

One of my problems is to access the instance variable `password` within the `static void` call and my other problem is that I get SIGABRT when I try to call the method (I used a fixed string to test if that works).

Is there any possibility to get that working ?!

Julian

Answer (score 0):

`kbdCallback` is not actually a method, it's a function - you can tell a couple of ways - there's no `-` or `+` in front of it, no parentheses around the return type, and also methods cannot be `static`. So, due to it being a function and not a method, there is no object associated with it, and no `self` pointer; thus you cannot get to any instance variables directly. There's a couple of ways to solve this I suppose; you could have a static instance of your object that the function could get the password from, or if there's some way to pass a context pointer to be used in the callback you might be able to pass an object in that way.

Regarding your `SIGABRT`, can you say which line exactly that happens on, and what the values of the arguments that you're using are? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Actually I cannot pass any context pointer to the function. When I change the passed parameters, I get a warning in line one (corresponding to my code from above): `incompatible pointer types passing`. The `SIABRT` happens on line one too.

Comment: @Julian you'll probably have to do something unpleasant like store the username and password in `static` variables while awaiting the callback. Also, can you say what the values of the arguments are being passed in to `libssh2_userauth_keyboard_interactive` when it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.network.ssh.libssh2.devel/4163

**Cause:** malloc-in-EXE-free-in-DLL under Win32.
**Fix:** Use custom free/malloc/realloc functions. Add below

```
static void *my_alloc(size_t count, void **abstract)            {   return malloc(count);}
static void my_free(void *ptr, void **abstract)                 {   free(ptr);}
static void *my_realloc(void *ptr, size_t count, void **abstract){  return realloc(ptr, count);}
```

And replace

```
libssh2_session_init();
```

with

```
libssh2_session_init_ex(my_alloc, my_free, my_realloc, NULL);
```